# ElectronJs: How to send message from ipcMain to IpcRender and then receive a reply?

Tags: javascript, electron

I'm sending a message to asking render to parse html string

```
mainWindow.webContents.send('parse html', { resp})
```

Rendere processes the data and sends reply

```
ipc.on('parse html',function(e,p){
            let body = $(p.resp.body)
            let player = body.find('#player')[0]
             const mi =  $(player).find('script:not([src])')[0].innerText 
            let sl =  mi.split(";")[0]
            sl = sl.replace("var flashvars_229661792 =",'')
            pJson = JSON.parse(sl)

             console.log(pJson);
             ipc.send('json:parsed',{pJson})

        })
```

But the main process is not getting the reply

```
mainWindow.webContents.on('json:parsed', (event,request)=> {
       console.log(request);

     });
```

Answer (score 0):

whoops. I was doing it wrong
it's

```
ipc.on('json:parsed', (event,request)=> {
       console.log(request);

     });
```